# Get confidence of Google Vision OCR text annotation result

Tags: ocr, google-vision

The results I get from running OCR on an image (based on [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr)) don't include a confidence score. Is there a way to get this information?

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.vision.v1#entityannotation) lists `score` as one of the values that should be returned, but I don't see it.

This is the output I see:

```
description: "&"
bounding_poly {
  vertices {
    x: 435
    y: 959
  }
  vertices {
    x: 459
    y: 960
  }
  vertices {
    x: 458
    y: 990
  }
  vertices {
    x: 434
    y: 989
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your link to the documentation goes to the section of "entity annotation" which is not relevant for OCR.

You can get some kind of score (confidence) for OCR results if you set the type of your request to "DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION":

```
....
 "symbols": [
                          {
                            "property": {
                              "detectedLanguages": [
                                {
                                  "languageCode": "en"
                                }
                              ]
                            },
                            "boundingBox": {
                              "vertices": [....]
                            },
                            "text": "T",
                            "confidence": 0.99
                          }, 
....
```

The results for the type "TEXT_DETECTION" will NOT give you any confidence values.

You can try the difference easily here: 
https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr